# Way to combine two case expressions that populate two separate variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, case-when

I have a stored procedure that takes user inputs and then returns two values. Currently I have 2 `case-when` expressions that do the job for me, but I am trying to figure out if I can combine the 2 expressions to have simpler, neater code.

Below is my current `case-when` code

```
DECLARE @SpecialsVariable varchar(max)
DECLARE @SpecialName varchar(64) 

SET @SpecialsVariable = CASE @Special
                           WHEN 'Petr_analysis' THEN 'RAW_ColloTel,RAW_DetroCol'
                           WHEN 'AFT_analysis' THEN 'RAW_Defo,RAW_Defr,RAW_Floo,RAW_Flor'
                           WHEN 'Fisch_analysis' THEN 'RAW_COke,RAW_Gas,RAW_H2O,RAW_Tar'
                        END

SET @SpecialName =  CASE @Special
                       WHEN 'Petr_analysis' THEN 'Petrography'
                       WHEN 'AFT_analysis' THEN 'Ash Fusion Temperature'
                       WHEN 'Fisch_analysis' THEN 'Fischer-Tropsch'
                    END
```

I tried the code below but I get an error regarding the comma between the 2 set variables

```
DECLARE @Special varchar(64) = 'Petr_analysis'
DECLARE @SpecialsVariable varchar(max)
DECLARE @SpecialName varchar(64) 

set @SpecialName, @SpecialsVariable =  case @Special
    when 'Petr_analysis' then 'Petrography', 'RAW_ColloTel,RAW_DetroCol'
    when 'AFT_analysis' then 'Ash Fusion Temperature', 'RAW_Defo,RAW_Defr,RAW_Floo,RAW_Flor'
    when 'Fisch_analysis' then 'Fischer-Tropsch', 'RAW_COke,RAW_Gas,RAW_H2O,RAW_Tar'
end
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.
A `case` expression can only return a scalar value for each condition.

What you can do, however, is use a table and populate your variables using a select statement:

```
CREATE TABLE SpecialMapping -- Find a better name for this, please
(
    Special varchar(64),
    Name varchar(64), 
    Variable varchar(max) -- Do you really need max here? 
)

INSERT INTO SpecialMapping (Sepcial, Name, Variable) VALUES
('Petr_analysis', 'Petrography', 'RAW_ColloTel,RAW_DetroCol'),
('AFT_analysis', 'Ash Fusion Temperature', 'RAW_Defo,RAW_Defr,RAW_Floo,RAW_Flor'),
('Fisch_analysis', 'Fischer-Tropsch', 'RAW_COke,RAW_Gas,RAW_H2O,RAW_Tar');
```

and in the stored procedure:

```
SELECT @SpecialName = Name
     , @SpecialsVariable = Variable 
FROM SpecialMapping
WHERE WHERE Special = @Special;
```

Comment: The varchar(max) is used currently as I haven't get determined the best length-size. For the question I shortend some of the @SpecialsVariable values.

Comment: BTW, you really shouldn't be using delimited strings in SQL. ([Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/3094533))

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can combine them like that.

I think your options are

- Set the variables independently, like your first block
- Nested if statements
- Create a reference table

Example for Nested if

```
IF @Special = 'Petr_analysis' 
    BEGIN 
    (set your variables) 
    END 
ELSE IF @Special = 'AFT_analysis'
    BEGIN
    ...
```

Example of reference table with the three columns e.g., Special, SpecialsVariable, SpecialName

```
SELECT  @SpecialVariable = yt.SpecialVariable, 
        @SpecialName = yt.SpecialName 
FROM    yourtable yt 
WHERE   yt.Special = @Special
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a once off kind of requirement, another alternative might be to use table value constructors:

e.g.:

```
DECLARE @SpecialsVariable varchar(max)
DECLARE @SpecialName varchar(64) 
DECLARE @Special varchar(30) =  'Petr_analysis'

select @SpecialsVariable = tab.Variable, @SpecialName = tab.Name from
    (VALUES 
         ('Petr_analysis', 'RAW_ColloTel,RAW_DetroCol',  'Petrography'),
         ('AFT_analysis', 'RAW_Defo,RAW_Defr,RAW_Floo,RAW_Flor', 'Ash Fusion Temperature'),
         ('Fisch_analysis', 'RAW_COke,RAW_Gas,RAW_H2O,RAW_Tar', 'Fischer-Tropsch')         
    ) tab (Special, Variable, Name) 
    where tab.Special = @Special
```

Info on Table Value Constructors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15